# sails js unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I have creted a sails js application. I want to add unit testing for my application. I am using following approach to do the unit testing.
http://sailsjs-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/Testing/

I am using grunt to test my application with mocha. Now I need a way to override some sails methods (find, update, etc. ) to use for my testing, since I do not want interact with the database when testing the code. Is there a way override sails js methods. As an example when I use User.find method in my testing, I want to have a specific result to test my other methods work perfectly. Any kind of help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do testing wihout touching production database, you can use different table/ collection of your database. It's common approach in integration testing (not using a mock).

Here is the example, in file `bootstrap.test.js`

```
var Sails = require('sails'),
    sails;

before(function (done) {
  Sails.lift({
    connections: {
      mongodbServer: {
        database: 'database_test'
      }
    },
    models     : {
      migrate: 'drop'
    }
  }, function (err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);

    done();
  });
});

after(function (done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);
});
```

It's assumed that your connection use `mongodbServer` and db `database_test`. Configure it to meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer andi, I have read some articles about teting, most of them said that unit teting should be finished quickly after we execute them. So u beleive using a mock would be a good idea, but i could not find any specific way to   use a mock in sails to override sails built in functions or other methods.

Comment: It's true that `unit testing` and `integration testing` is different. My solution is actually for integration testing. Because (just my opinion) pure unit testing in Sails's models is hard to achieve, also it give less advantages.

But if you still want to, try to use `sinon`. Here is the reference [@Github](https://github.com/fdvj/wolfpack/issues/2).

Comment: I am writing test cases inside my test/unit/controllers and test/unit/models. in my grunt file how can I use bootstrap.test.js file to run all the test inside my unit folder. Now I am running test files individually using grunt.

Comment: I just use `npm test` without Grunt. Just edit `package.json` and add `test` field under `scripts` field with value similar to this `"test": "_mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.js --no-timeouts",` It will read all `js` files under `test/unit`

Comment: Thank you for the answer Andi. I tried to use a test database and run the tests using npm test. But it gives and error saying 'A hook (`orm`) failed to load!', do you have any idea about this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I remove migrate: 'drop' option, this works perfectly.

Comment: It's some kind of ORM bug in Sails. It also happens to me sometimes, I don't know either how to solve it. But that kind of error only occurs in the beginning of testing. Try to run the test few more later, maybe it will solve in the next run.

Comment: unit tests should not spin up server or hit databases/do i/o